# After the scroll top animation, the window doesn't scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing the scrollTop method, but it doesn't play properly. When I click on a paragraph element the scroll to the top runs smoothly.I get to the #map element but I cannot scroll after the click event. The window doesn't scroll down. Here is the js code for you to see.

```
    jQuery('area').each(function(){

var values =jQuery( this ).attr('data-nid');
jQuery( this ).append('<p>'+values+'</p>');
                   jQuery( this ).closest("#membermap").find('p').click(function () {
                        $("html, body").animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#map").offset().top
                        }, 600);
                        return false;
                    });

  });
```

Here is my html code: `

```
    <map class="imagemap" id="membermap" name="membermap">
        <area data-nid="513" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="54,173,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="566" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="76,181,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="490" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="73,189,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="715" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="115,205,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="717" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="132,212,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="481" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="96,224,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="476" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="476" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="476" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="715" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="115,205,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="717" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="132,212,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="481" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="96,224,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="456" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="426" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="456" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="730" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="115,205,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="753" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="132,212,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="42" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="96,224,3" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="246" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="426" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
        <area data-nid="473" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="133,315,32" href="" target=""></area>
    </map>
```

`

Comment: Provide your html quick?

Comment: What is meant by: _the window hoops_? It would be good if you reproduced your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: also your code says that you have same ids for multiple elements in the page.

Comment: @Sidd The window kinda of jumps and doesnt let me scroll down to the page

Comment: @Sergiti I change your code a little bit, but it look like your js code is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/pj0uzb8u/1/

Comment: thnx @tsuensiu but i still cannot scroll down.